# Symfony 2 -security.yml: How to create an exception pattern inside the firewalls?

Tags: security, symfony, design-patterns

**example:** I have this inside my firewalls

```
 secured_area:
             pattern:    ^/
             form_login:
                 check_path: /secured/login_check
                 login_path: /secured/login
             logout:
                 path:   /secured/logout
                 target: /
             context: primary_auth
```

I would like to access to this pattern => `^/toto` without login.

Please, help me ?

Answer (score 1):

With this, anyone can access it.

```
#change with your path
security:
    secured_area:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /secured/login_check
            login_path: /secured/login
        logout:
            path:   /secured/logout
            target: /
        context: primary_auth

    access_control:
        - { path: /toto, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ , roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Edit :

Don't forget your anonymous : ~ (let anonymous user use it (for toto))

and let authorization via your access_control

Comment: can you copy your security:  access_control : ?

Comment: login:
        pattern:  ^/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /secured/login_check
            login_path: /secured/login
        logout:
            path:   /secured/logout
            target: /
        context: primary_auth

access_control:
  - { path: /toto, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

Comment: please share a git gist of your security file https://gist.github.com/ , it s unreadable :D

Comment: i commt your gist and edit answer , it this code and it works

Comment: thank you so much. Now it's working on => "app_dev" but not on =>"app" and i have already made a cache clear

Comment: it is an other problem i think, are you sure you really clear the "prod" cache and not the dev ? This problem does not come from this code

Comment: it's ok thank you, the command => php app/console cache:clear clean only the dev.

Comment: cache:clear --env="prod" . Close this with accepting this answer or not :p

Comment: It's not working again only because in the roles i put 2 role for one path =>https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d36a7980663a01facd2

Comment: You can't put 2 roles , you should look roles hierarchy. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-role-hierarchy post an other question if it s not clear , and give me the url :D

Comment: if a put a role to this pattern => ^/ i can't go to the pattern => /toto https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f11ca8219205342c07d4

Comment: my cache want to make me crazy